# How to insert data from a column of an existing table into another existing table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want to insert data from a column of an existing  table into another existing table . i am doing this in MVC3 using Entity Framework. The data is added from a controller  to the table through  a view. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your data from the old table.

example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
var blogs = from b in context.Blogs 
               where b.Name.StartsWith("B") 
               select b; 

// Query for the Blog named ADO.NET Blog 
var blog = context.Blogs 
                .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

2. Insert your data to the new table.

example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blog = new Blog { Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 
    context.Blogs.Add(blog); 
    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```